# angular POST not working as expected (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using angular to make a POST request on click using the following code in my controller...

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "../submit.php",
    data: {
        templateData: $scope.template

    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

I send the data to a php file called `submit.php` and everything works fine, `submit.php` receives the data. Next thing I do with the data is write it to a file...

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$contentFile = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($contentFile, $template);
fclose($contentFile);
```

This seems to work, I get not errors. But now, the next thing I want to happen is to download the file to the browser. This code should work but it does not download to the browser for some reason...

```
header('Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache', true);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"");
```

FULL CODE

```
<?php 

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $template = "";
    foreach ($request as $data) {
        foreach ($data as $sub) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($sub); $i++) {
                $template .= $sub[$i];
            }

        }
     }


$contentFile = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($contentFile, $template);
fclose($contentFile);

header('Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache', true);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"");

?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the person viewing your site to download the file? There's not really a way to force your users to download something, because that would be a big security vulnerability.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin something like that, you press download button, and I want it to take the string a write it to a file, which then downloads it onto the user's computer

Comment: What is happening now? Is the file (it's content) shown in the browser?

Comment: @Jeff yeah if I echo the content it is shown

Comment: @Jeff also if I change the url to `submit.php` an empty file is downloaded to the browser, but I need the file with its content to be downloaded on click from my `index.php`

Comment: but what happens now, with the provided code (without echo)?

Comment: @Jeff It tells me that the file was written successfully, but the last chunck of code above seems to be ignored

Comment: ah! you have an `echo` somewhere, which you didn't show here!? Any output before a header will disable the header. Also you didn't show how you output the file.

Comment: @Jeff ok I removed the echo but it still seems to be disabled

Comment: @Jeff There it is my full submit.php

Comment: You don't get errors because you never check for them. PHP returns boolean false whenever a file operation fails. it doesn't spit out warnings/errors/exceptions. And then you never actually OUTPUT your file. you just output some headers that say will be a file.

Comment: @MarcB what I did was `readfile` and it gave me the correct output, so I assume the write was a success based on that

Comment: If you add `echo $template` at the very end it should work (for a simple text-file).
 You don't really need to actually write and save a file for such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you missed is to actually *output* your "file".

```
<?php 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$template = "";
foreach ($request as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $sub) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($sub); $i++) {
            $template .= $sub[$i];
        }

    }
}

header('Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache', true);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"");

// here's the thing:
echo $template;
?>
```

This only works for text/plain.
You don't need to save the content to a file first.

*NOTE*
You can never enforce a browser to "download" a file. Some browsers might decide to display that file. The "stranger" the file is, the more likely the user will be prompted to download.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $postdata = file_get_conteenter code herents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $template = "";
    foreach ($request as $data) {
        foreach ($data as $sub) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($sub); $i++) {
                $template .= $sub[$i];
            }

        }
     }


$contentFile = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($contentFile, $template);
fclose($contentFile);

/************
Return full path of text file in json
***********/

?>
```

and in ajax success you can open that file in new window using window.location function.